# Where read recent developments in Math presented in a way that is easy to understand?

Tags: reference-request, education

I posted a similar question a few months ago, but I don't think people understood my question. I often find articles such as [this](http://abcnews.go.com/Technology/evolution-action-michigan-state-scientists-grow-coli-56000/story?id=17329160) which discuss exciting developments in science. I have a great interest in Math, but I am an engineer who has been away from academics for about 20 years. I would like to read articles that I can understand about recent research in math. I did find a nice example [here](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/frank-morgan/bees-honeycomb-mathematics_b_1318258.html) about tiling a plane with pentagons. Is there a web-site with articles that discuss receant math research at that level?

Comment: Maybe you can find things here: http://www.maa.org/

Comment: You might also want to look at: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/15366/which-journals-publish-expository-work

Comment: It would be helpful if you would include a link to your similar question so people will know what you *don't* want to see.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson: I couldn't find the link to my similar question. I even looked up all questions I posted.